# Unix Parse Varying Named Value into seperate rows

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

We are getting a varying length input file as mentioned below. The text is varying length.

Input file:

```
ID|Text
1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;name5=value5
2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8
```

The text here has named value pair as the content and it's of varying length. Please note that the name in the text column can contain a semi colon. We are trying to parse the input but we are not able handle it via AWK or BASH

Desired Output:

```
1|name1=value1
1|name3;name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

The below snipped of code works for ID=2, but doesn't for ID=1

```
echo "2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8" | while IFS="|"; read id text;do dsc=`echo $text|tr ';' '\n'`;echo "$dsc" >tmp;done
cat tmp
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

```
echo "1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;name5=value5" | while IFS="|"; read id text;do dsc=`echo $text|tr ';' '\n'`;echo "$dsc" >tmp;sed -i "s/^/${id}\|/g" tmp;done
cat tmp
1|name1=value1
1|name3
1|name4=value2
1|name5=value5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've mentioned using `awk` and `bash` but have not shown any code with these references; please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then consider updating your question accordingly (eg, provide sample inputs, your code attempts, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output)

Comment: So is the output you posted the output you want to display or the output from what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show us the output you are looking for?

Comment: @RamanSailopal - Thank you for your response. Yes the output posted is how I want to display. Could you please suggest a way. The below code works for ID = 2, but it doesn't for ID = 1 from my example.

echo "2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8" | while IFS="|"; read id text;do dsc=`echo $text|tr ';' '\n'`;echo "$dsc" >tmp;sed -i "s/^/${id}\|/g" tmp;done

cat tmp
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8

Comment: @markp-fuso: Thank you. Here is what I tried - this works for ID = 2, but doesn't for ID = 1:

echo "2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8" | while IFS="|"; read id text;do dsc=`echo $text|tr ';' '\n'`;echo "$dsc" >tmp;sed -i "s/^/${id}\|/g" tmp;done

cat tmp
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8

echo "1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;;name5=value5" | while IFS="|"; read id text;do dsc=`echo $text|tr ';' '\n'`;echo "$dsc" >tmp;sed -i "s/^/${id}\|/g" tmp;done

1|name1=value1
1|name3
1|name4=value2
1|
1|name5=value5

Comment: please edit the question to include your additional details; not everyone is going to take the time to read through the comments in an attempt to piece together the whole picture; thanks

Comment: in your sample data for the line where `ID=1` there is a double semicolon between `value2` and `name5` => `value2;;name5` ... should this be a single semicolon?

Comment: @markp-fuso - It was an inadvertent typo, corrected it now. I also added the code snippet that works only for ID = 2 but not for ID = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk` with new version of it. Since OP's `awk` version is old so if anyone having old version of `awk` then try changing it to `awk --re-interval`

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==1{ next }
{
  first=$1
  while(match($0,/(name[0-9]+;?){1,}=(value[0-9]+)?/)){
    print first,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1|name1=value1
1|name3;name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above(following is for explanation purposes only).

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS="|"                                 ##Setting FS and OFS wiht | here.
}
FNR==1{ next }                               ##If line is first line then go next, do not print anything.
{
  first=$1                                   ##Creating first and setting as first field here.
  while(match($0,/(name[0-9]+;?){1,}=(value[0-9]+)?/)){
##Running while loop which has match which has a regex of matching name and value all mentioned permutations and combinations.
    print first,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Printing first and sub string(currently matched one)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)             ##Saving rest of the line into current line.
  }
}' Input_file                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: cat Input_file
1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;name5=value5
2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8

I tried below but it doesn't return any output.

awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==1{next}
{
  first=$1
  while(match($0,/(name[0-9]+;?){1,}=(value[0-9]+)?/)){
    print first,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}'  Input_file

When I use man awk, I see that we have gawk - pattern scanning and processing language. Please advise if I'm missing anything

Comment: @seanarcher7, sorry I didn't get it(solution worked for given samples), please explain it more clearly what you are trying to convey here.

Comment: i used the command you gave, but it doesn't return any output. Our version of awk is 3.1.7

awk --v
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: @seanarcher7, my solution needs GNU awk with new version. May you could try changing from `awk '` to `awk --re-interval '` once? It was an old option to make ERE work in old awks, let me know if that helps you?

Comment: sure Ravinder. Thank you for the helpful comments too.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data:

```
$ cat name.dat
ID|Text
1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;name5=value5
2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F"[|;]" '                                                           # use "|" and ";" as input field delimiters
FNR==1 { next }                                                          # skip header line
       { pfx=$1 "|"                                                      # set output prefix to field 1 + "|"
         printpfx=1                                                      # set flag to print prefix

         for ( i=2 ; i<=NF ; i++ )                                       # for fields 2 to NF
             {
               if ( printpfx)     { printf "%s",   pfx  ; printpfx=0 }   # if print flag == 1 then print prefix and clear flag
               if ( $(i)  ~ /=/ ) { printf "%s\n", $(i) ; printpfx=1 }   # if current field contains "=" then print it, end this line of output, reset print flag == 1
               if ( $(i) !~ /=/ ) { printf "%s;",  $(i) }                # if current field does not contain "=" then print it and include a ";" suffix
             }
       }
' name.dat
```

The above generates:

```
1|name1=value1
1|name3;name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

Comment: @seanarcher7 sounds good; as RavinderSingh has pointed out, if one particular answer best addresses your issue then consider 'accept'ing said answer

Answer (score 1):

A Bash solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=\| read -r id text || [ -n "$id" ]; do
  IFS=\; read -r -a kv_arr < <(printf %s "$text")
  printf "$id|%s\\n" "${kv_arr[@]}"
done < <(tail -n +2 a.txt)
```

A plain POSIX shell solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Chop the header line from the input file
tail -n +2 a.txt |
# While reading id and text Fields Separated by vertical bar
while IFS=\| read -r id text || [ -n "$id" ]; do
  # Sets the separator to a semicolon
  IFS=\;
  # Print each semicolon separated field formatted on
  # its own line with the ID
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Explicit split on semicolon
  printf "$id|%s\\n" $text
done
```

Input `a.txt`:

```
ID|Text
1|name1=value1;name3;name4=value2;name5=value5
2|name1=value1;name2=value2;name6=;name7=value7;name8=value8
```

Output:

```
1|name1=value1
1|name3
1|name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however the POSIX solution has the same problem for ID=1 as I reported. 

tail -n +2 a.txt |
> while IFS=\| read -r id text || [ -n "$id" ]; do
>   IFS=\;
>   printf "$id|%s\\n" $text
> done
1|name1=value1
1|name3
1|name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8

Instead the output should be like this:

1|name1=value1
1|name3;name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8

Comment: @seanarcher7 This is exactly the output I get.

Comment: @LéaGris; 2nd/3rd lines of output need to be combined into `1|name3;name4=value2`

Answer (score 0):

You have some good answers and an accepted one already. Here is a much shorter gnu awk command that can also do the job:

```sh
awk -F '|' 'NR > 1 {
   for (s=$2; match(s, /([^=]+=[^;]*)(;|$)/, m); s=substr(s, RLENGTH+1))
      print $1 FS m[1]      
}' file.txt
```

```
1|name1=value1
1|name3;name4=value2
1|name5=value5
2|name1=value1
2|name2=value2
2|name6=
2|name7=value7
2|name8=value8
```

Comment: @seanarcher7: Please try this and comment here if it doesn't work